# HTTP PATH for Redis Health Check in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Im setting up ALB for Redis deployed on Amazon ECS Fargate. But Im not able to figure out the HTTP Path for Health Check in AWS Target Groups. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've missed something in the newer versions of Redis, Redis is not an HTTP server, so I don't think you will be able to use an ALB with Redis. I believe an NLB would be more appropriate.

Comment: That Worked ! .. Im trying to reference this NLB URL on my Airflow Workers ands Schedulers. Im using  Puckel Docker Image. Some how when i give this URL to REDIS_HOST Environmental variable, its querying <URL>:6379/1 and getting connection error. I believe its due to port number. Can ou help with this ?